# R- multiply columns that match a naming pattern

Tags: r

I have multiple columns in a data frame that follow the same naming convention. Lets say I have:

```
    a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2
1    0    0   0   0
2    0    0   0   0
```

I want to multiply the values in a_1 by the values in b_1, and the values in a_2 by the values in b_2, hypothetically a_3 * b_3, ....., and so on.

What are some ways I can accomplish this and insert the information into a new column?

Comment: `m[,paste0("a_", 1:n)] * m[,paste0("b_", 1:n)]`, where `n` is the number of each column you have, should compute all the products. You could add that  as new columns of your matrix with `cbind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comment of "**josliber**",Thanks for the inputs here. Here is my solution.

1) Determine the pattern, use str_extract_all from `stringr` package to extract the pattern(Used positive lookaround) to extract "a_" and "b_".The solution would work even if the pattern changes to something like "ABC_" and "XYZ_", as long as it follows the original pattern. **However, the solution won't work in case if the pattern columns are not equal or the pattern is completely different.**

2) Determine the "mult" to check the number of columns against each pattern.

3) Use "*" to multiply the columns.

4) Cbind the columns to get the final result.

```
    train <- data.frame(a_1 = 1:5,a_2 = 2:6,b_1 = 11:15, b_2 = 12:16,a_3 = 21:25, b_3 = 22:26)
    library(stringr)

    vect <- str_extract_all(names(train),"(\\w*_)(?=\\d*)",simplify=T)[,1]
    vect <- unique(vect)

    ###determine the number of of columns against eatch match , for ex. "a_" would have 3 and so on.
    mult <- ncol(train)/length(vect)

dat2 <- train[,paste0(vect[1], 1:mult)] * train[,paste0(vect[2], 1:mult)]
names(dat2)  <- paste0(vect[1],vect[2],1:mult)
datfinal <- data.frame(cbind(train,dat2))
```

**Answer:**

```
   > datfinal
  a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2 a_3 b_3 a_b_1 a_b_2 a_b_3
1   1   2  11  12  21  22    11    24   462
2   2   3  12  13  22  23    24    39   506
3   3   4  13  14  23  24    39    56   552
4   4   5  14  15  24  25    56    75   600
5   5   6  15  16  25  26    75    96   650
```

Answer (score 0):

A random data frame with a naming convention:

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(runif(24),ncol=4))
colnames(df)<-c("lolz_1","lolz_2", "lel_1", "lel_2")
```

This is similar to what was suggested in the comments:

```
df$new_col<-df[, grepl("lolz", names(df))]*df[, grepl("lel", names(df))]
```